# shivery effect of the GUI prepared using C# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

For file transfer between the client and server systems we have a GUI designed on the client system using C# windows forms. We have added a lot of background images and text boxes to make the GUI impressive. But whenever we execute the client code, the GUI takes a few seconds to load itself and be stable , before a choice from the GUI can be made. This happens after every request made from the client side GUI.(its like all the form elements vanish and appear again in a short span of time ). Please help with this. May i know the reason for it.

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Client405
{
    public partial class RequestForm : Form
    {
        #region Variables
        internal static ListBox FileListBox;
        internal static byte[] RecievedFile = new byte[46000000];
        internal static string StoragePath = string.Empty;
        internal static bool CacheSelected = false;
        internal static string ChosenTech = "Default";
        internal static bool EnableCompression = false;
        //internal static string FileType;
        internal static string SelectedFile = string.Empty;
        internal static Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        #endregion

        public RequestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(RequestForm_Load);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        void RequestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ComprMsgLabel.Text = "Compression Technique chosen is :" + ChosenTech;
            FileListBox = new ListBox();
            FileName_textBox.Enabled = true;
            FileName_textBox.ReadOnly = true;

            if (!Connections.SocketConnected())
            {
                Connections.EstablishConnectionWithServer();
            }

            if (LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                EnableCompression = true;
                CacheSelected = true;
                RegisterlinkLabel.Visible = false;

                HighRB.Enabled = true;
                LowRB.Enabled = true;
                MediumRB.Enabled = true;
                CacheMsg_label.Text = "Caching Enabled";
            }
            else if (!LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                RegisterlinkLabel.Visible = true;
                RegisterlinkLabel.Show();
                Logout_Label.Text = "Home Page";
                Cache_checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                Cache_checkBox.Enabled = false;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Enabled = false;
                HighRB.Enabled = false;
                LowRB.Enabled = false;
                MediumRB.Enabled = false;
                DefaultRB.Visible = false;
                NoneRB.Visible = false;
                DefaultRB.Enabled = false;
                NoneRB.Enabled = false;
                CacheMsg_label.Text = "Caching Disabled";
            }

            ChosenTech = "None";
            LogUser_Label.Text = LogUser_Label.Text + LoginAuthenticator.myCurrentUser;
            SetClientInfo();
        }

        private void SetClientInfo()
        {
            //LogUser_Label.Text = LoginAuthenticator.myCurrentUser;
            HostValue_Label.Text = HelperInfo.HostNameValue;

            //Add port info
            Port_Value.Text = HelperInfo.PortNumber;

            //Add IP address
            IPAddr_value.Text = HelperInfo.IPAddress_client;

            //Add Gateway info
            Gateway_value.Text = HelperInfo.Default_Gateway;

            //Add the ip address of server connected to
            ServerIP_Value_Label.Text = HelperInfo.Connected_To(Connections.myClientSocket);

            if (Connections.myClientSocket.Connected)
            {
                ONOFF_radio.Text = "Online";
            }
            else
            {
                ONOFF_radio.Text = "Offline";
            }
        }

        private void GetFile_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((AudioRB.Checked == false) && (ImageRB.Checked == false) && (TextRB.Checked == false))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a File Type");
                return;
            }

            if (SelectedFile == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select a File");
                return;
            }

            if (!LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                FileTransfer.UnRegisteredTransfer();
                this.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("Transaction Completed");
            }

            if (LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                DialogResult trans_reqd = DialogResult.No;
                //check Cache
                if (Cache_checkBox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                {
                    trans_reqd = FileCache.TransactionQuery(RequestForm.SelectedFile);
                    if (trans_reqd == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        string[] files = { System.IO.Path.Combine(@"D:\\FT\\Cache", RequestForm.SelectedFile), System.IO.Path.Combine(@"D:\\FT\\Downloads", RequestForm.SelectedFile) };

                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(files[1]))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(files[1]);
                        }
                        System.IO.File.Copy(files[0], files[1]);
                        watch.Stop();
                    }
                    else          //if not in cacheF
                    {
                        FileTransfer.RegisteredTransfer();
                    }
                }
                else                //if caching not enabled
                {

                    FileTransfer.RegisteredTransfer();
                }

                this.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("Transaction Completed");
            }
        }

        private void AudioRB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ChosenTech = "Default";
            if (AudioRB.Checked == true)
            {
                ImageRB.Checked = false;
                TextRB.Checked = false;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Visible = false;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Enabled = false;
                FileListBox.Hide();
                DisplayRadioButtons();
                SelectedFile = string.Empty;
                FileName_textBox.Text = string.Empty;
                FileTransfer.FileType = "Audio";
                //ViewFiles_button.Visible = true;
                ViewFiles();
            }
            else if (AudioRB.Checked == false)
            {
                //ViewFiles_button.Visible = false;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Visible = true;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Enabled = true;
                FileListBox.Hide();
            }
        }

        private void ViewFiles()
        {
            FileTransfer.GetFileNames();
            this.Controls.Add(RequestForm.FileListBox);
            RequestForm.FileListBox.BringToFront();
            RequestForm.FileListBox.Visible = true;
            RequestForm.FileListBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            //RequestForm.SelectedFile = FileTransfer.FileListView.SelectedItems[0].Text;
            //FileName_textBox.Text = RequestForm.SelectedFile;
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileName_textBox.Text = FileListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            RequestForm.SelectedFile = FileName_textBox.Text;
        }

        private void ImageRB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChosenTech = "Default";
            if (ImageRB.Checked == true && LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                AudioRB.Checked = false;
                TextRB.Checked = false;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Enabled = true;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Visible = true;
                FileListBox.Hide();
                FileTransfer.FileType = "Image";
                SelectedFile = string.Empty;
                FileName_textBox.Text = string.Empty;
                DisplayRadioButtons();
                ViewFiles();
                //ViewFiles_button.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (ImageRB.Checked == true && !LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                AudioRB.Checked = false;
                TextRB.Checked = false;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Enabled = false;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Visible = true;
                FileListBox.Hide();
                FileTransfer.FileType = "Image";
                SelectedFile = string.Empty;
                FileName_textBox.Text = string.Empty;
                DisplayRadioButtons();
                ViewFiles();
            }
            else if (ImageRB.Checked == false)
            {
                //ViewFiles_button.Visible = false;
                RequestForm.FileListBox.Hide();
            }
        }

        private void TextRB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChosenTech = "Default";
            if (TextRB.Checked == true && LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {

                ImageRB.Checked = false;
                AudioRB.Checked = false;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Enabled = true;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Visible = true;
                RequestForm.FileListBox.Hide();
                DisplayRadioButtons();
                FileTransfer.FileType = "Text";
                SelectedFile = string.Empty;
                FileName_textBox.Text = string.Empty;
                ViewFiles();
                //ViewFiles_button.Visible = true;

            }
            else if (TextRB.Checked == true && !LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                ImageRB.Checked = false;
                AudioRB.Checked = false;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Enabled = false;
                EnableCompr_checkBox.Visible = true;
                RequestForm.FileListBox.Hide();
                DisplayRadioButtons();
                FileTransfer.FileType = "Text";
                SelectedFile = string.Empty;
                FileName_textBox.Text = string.Empty;
                ViewFiles();
            }
            else if (TextRB.Checked == false)
            {
                //ViewFiles_button.Visible = false;
                RequestForm.FileListBox.Hide();
            }
        }

        private void Cache_checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Cache_checkBox.Checked)
            {
                CacheMsg_label.Text = "Caching Enabled";
                CacheSelected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                CacheMsg_label.Text = "Caching Disabled";
                CacheSelected = false;
            }
        }

        private void EnableCompr_checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRadioButtons();
        }

        internal void DisplayRadioButtons()
        {
            if (EnableCompr_checkBox.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
            {
                HighRB.Enabled = false;
                MediumRB.Enabled = false;
                LowRB.Enabled = false;
                HighRB.Visible = false;
                MediumRB.Visible = false;
                LowRB.Visible = false;
                DefaultRB.Enabled = false;
                DefaultRB.Visible = false;
                NoneRB.Enabled = false;
                NoneRB.Visible = false;
            }
            if (EnableCompr_checkBox.Checked && FileTransfer.FileType == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a FileType.\nAssociated Compression techniques available will be shown.");
                EnableCompr_checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            }

            if (EnableCompr_checkBox.Checked && FileTransfer.FileType == "Text" && LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                DefaultRB.Enabled = true;
                DefaultRB.Visible = true;
                NoneRB.Visible = true;
                NoneRB.Enabled = true;
                HighRB.Enabled = false;
                MediumRB.Enabled = false;
                LowRB.Enabled = false;
                HighRB.Visible = false;
                MediumRB.Visible = false;
                LowRB.Visible = false;

                ComprMsgLabel.Text = "Chosen Compression technique : Default";
            }
            else if (EnableCompr_checkBox.Checked && FileTransfer.FileType == "Text" && !LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                HighRB.Enabled = false;
                MediumRB.Enabled = false;
                LowRB.Enabled = false;
                HighRB.Visible = false;
                MediumRB.Visible = false;
                LowRB.Visible = false;
                NoneRB.Visible = false;
                DefaultRB.Visible = false;

                ComprMsgLabel.Text = "Chosen Compression technique : Default";
            }
            else if (EnableCompr_checkBox.Checked && FileTransfer.FileType == "Image" && LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                DefaultRB.Enabled = true;
                DefaultRB.Visible = true;
                NoneRB.Visible = true;
                NoneRB.Enabled = true;
                HighRB.Enabled = true;
                MediumRB.Enabled = true;
                LowRB.Enabled = true;
                HighRB.Visible = true;
                MediumRB.Visible = true;
                LowRB.Visible = true;
                ChosenTech = "Default";
                ComprMsgLabel.Text = "Chosen Compression technique : Default";
            }
            else if (EnableCompr_checkBox.Checked && FileTransfer.FileType == "Image" && !LoginAuthenticator.registered)
            {
                HighRB.Enabled = false;
                MediumRB.Enabled = false;
                LowRB.Enabled = false;
                HighRB.Visible = false;
                MediumRB.Visible = false;
                LowRB.Visible = false;
                DefaultRB.Visible = false;
                NoneRB.Visible = false;
                DefaultRB.Enabled = false;
                NoneRB.Enabled = false;
                ChosenTech = "VLOW";
                ComprMsgLabel.Text = "Chosen Compression technique : " + ChosenTech;
            }

        }

        private void NoneRB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileTransfer.FileType == "Text" && NoneRB.Checked == true)
            {
                ChosenTech = "None";
                DefaultRB.Checked = false;
            }
            else if (FileTransfer.FileType == "Image" && NoneRB.Checked == true)
            {
                ChosenTech = "None";
                DefaultRB.Checked = false;
                HighRB.Checked = false;
                LowRB.Checked = false;
                MediumRB.Checked = false;
            }
            else if (NoneRB.Checked == false)
            {
                ChosenTech = "Default";
            }

            ComprMsgLabel.Text = "Compression Technique chosen is :" + ChosenTech;
        }

        private void Logout_Label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connections.EndConnectionWithServer();

            Form1 newForm = new Form1();
            LoginAuthenticator.myCurrentUser = string.Empty;
            ChosenTech = string.Empty;
            FileTransfer.FileType = null;
            this.Hide();
            newForm.Show();
            MessageBox.Show("LogOut successful");
        }


        private void MediumRB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MediumRB.Checked == true)
            {
                ChosenTech = "MEDIUM";
                HighRB.Checked = false;
                LowRB.Checked = false;
                NoneRB.Checked = false;
            }
            else if (MediumRB.Checked == false)
            {
                ChosenTech = "Default";
            }

            ComprMsgLabel.Text = "Compression Technique chosen is :" + ChosenTech;
        }

        private void LowRB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LowRB.Checked == true)
            {
                ChosenTech = "LOW";
                HighRB.Checked = false;
                MediumRB.Checked = false;
                NoneRB.Checked = false;
            }
            else if (LowRB.Checked == false)
            {
                ChosenTech = "Default";
            }

            ComprMsgLabel.Text = "Compression Technique chosen is :" + ChosenTech;
        }

        private void HighRB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HighRB.Checked == true)
            {
                ChosenTech = "HIGH";
                LowRB.Checked = false;
                MediumRB.Checked = false;
                NoneRB.Checked = false;
            }
            else if (HighRB.Checked == false)
            {
                ChosenTech = "Default";
            }

            ComprMsgLabel.Text = "Compression Technique chosen is :" + ChosenTech;
        }

        private void statistics_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 statForm = new Form2();
            statForm.fileType_label.Text = statForm.fileType_label.Text + FileTransfer.FileType;
            statForm.fnstat_label.Text = statForm.fnstat_label.Text + SelectedFile;
            statForm.ASize_label.Text = statForm.ASize_label.Text + " " + FileTransfer.actualSize + " bytes";
            statForm.recSize_label.Text = statForm.recSize_label.Text + " " + FileTransfer.recSize + " bytes";
            statForm.rtt_label.Text = statForm.rtt_label.Text + " " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms";
            long percentage = ((FileTransfer.actualSize - FileTransfer.recSize) * 100) / FileTransfer.actualSize;
            statForm.BWsave.Text = statForm.BWsave.Text + " " + percentage + " %";
            statForm.Show();


            if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The time taken for the transaction is  : " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The time taken for the transaction is  : 1000 ");
            }
        }


        private void Folder_Select_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sd.InitialDirectory = @"D:\FT\";
            sd.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|ImageFiles (*.jpg)|*.jpg | Audio Files (*.mp3)|*.mp3";

            sd.ShowDialog();
            if (!File.Exists(sd.FileName))
            {
                FileStream fs = File.Create(sd.FileName);
                fs.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                FileStream fd = File.Open(sd.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                fd.Close();
            }
            StoragePath = sd.FileName;
        }

        private void RegisterlinkLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            Connections.EndConnectionWithServer();
            //MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Registration Details. ");
            Register regForm = new Register();
            regForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileTransfer.FileType == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select a File Type");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewFiles();
            }
        }

        private void Setting_Label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process myprocess = new Process();

            try
            {
                myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "http://" + HelperInfo.Default_Gateway + "//WANem";
                myprocess.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void FileName_textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that updates the form from the client code.

Comment: Using lots of background images that don't exactly fit the window or have a poor pixel format as well having lots of TextBox controls makes the painting of a window slow.  Why your form thinks it needs to repaint is entirely unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code in your form constructor.

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

It should improve some performance. Windows forms are not made to display lot of images overlapped on each other.

Comment: Ya must be so. Because we have included background images for labels along with the text box and also the group boxes. The above solution doesn't seem to work , but thanks.

Comment: I know it may be difficult, but if you post your code here, people will be able to help better. Currently no one knows why your code is repainting entire form element. Btw, double buffer should have helped you in such case but improvement may not be visible in many case.

Comment: We have 4 forms..signin, register, homepage and a request form. This problem occurs with request form since it has the most number of text boxes, labels and group boxes. I have posted the code..since its too long i have minimized the similar modules. Hope to find a solution.